# How to separate functions

Tags: javascript, function

I've got a problem because I don't know how to separate functions. I have code like this and I want to just call functions in then() statement but I don't know how to move them out because they have common variables.

```
.then(function(data){
  var rs = data.DL;
  var zones = [];
  var cluster = [];
  var loadStructure = [];

  function loadJsonData(rs, loadStructure) {
    //body method
    //creating zones[];
    //creating cluster[];
    return loadStructure;
  }

  function loadJsonInterZoneLinks(loadStructure, rs) {
    //body method
    //uses zones[]
    return loadStructure;
  }

  function loadJsonIntraZoneLinks(loadStructure, rs) {
    //body method
    //uses zones[] and cluster[]
    return loadStructure;
  }

  loadJsonData(loadStructure, rs);
  loadJsonInterZoneLinks(loadStructure, rs);
  return loadJsonIntraZoneLinks(loadStructure, rs);
})
```

Every function push new values to loadStructure and the last one return complete Array. I don't know how to move functions out of then() because of common variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following:-

```
function loadJsonData(rs) {
    //body method
    //creating loadStructure[];
    //creating zones[];
    //creating cluster[];

    var loadStructure= [];
    var zones = [];
    var cluster = [];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve([loadStructure, zones, cluster]);
    });
}

function loadJsonInterZoneLinks(rs, loadStructure, zones, cluster) {
    //body method
    //uses zones[]
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve([loadStructure, zones, cluster]);
    });
}

function loadJsonIntraZoneLinks(rs, loadStructure, zones, cluster) {
    //body method
    //uses zones[] and cluster[]
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve([loadStructure, zones, cluster]);
    });
}


yourfunction()
.then(function(data){
  var rs = data.DL;  
  return loadJsonData(rs);
})
.then(function(data) {
   return loadJsonInterZoneLinks(rs, data[0], data[1], data[2]);
})
.then(function(data) {
   return loadJsonIntraZoneLinks(rs, data[0], data[1], data[2]);
})
.then(function(data) {
  //HERE your final DATA return from here
});
```